# Facebook Share Buttom custom redirect

Tags: javascript, facebook, encodeuricomponent

I have a problem. I have a code share button on facebook because I want to share my blog posts. But a problem of logic makes me just get to share my posts if I "get them".
example:
In my main page (www.blog.com) posts all have the share button. Taking example, in the summary screen appears POST1. Still in all, I put the share button for easy access. That way the person need not open the post to see the buttons. However, if I click on any of the buttons that appear through the main screen, the button will share the link (www.blog.com) and not the post.
To share a post I need to click on the post to open the link it (www.blog.com/post1) and finally click the same button to share it (www.blog.com/post1), I believe it is because of "location .href ".

Anyway, my goal was to share the posts without having to extend them, a logical type: share through the address where that button is written, rather than sharing the button where the page is in the browser.

```
<a href="data:post.url" onclick=" window.open( 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436'); return false;" >
<img border="0" src="http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/xq90/538/xKHv0R.png"></img >
```

Thank you

Comment: location.href is the url that is currently in the url bar in the browser.

Comment: I know, and I do not want that to happen because the link would be (www.blog.com) and not the post, the way I want: (www.blog.com/post1)